# view animation from bottom to top

Tags: ios, swift4

I am trying to animate the view ,means need to increase the view height slowly unto certain height from bottom.I tried some animation but it is animating from bottom to top.I don't want that.If any one help me to do this would be great.Thanks in advance.

```
extension UIView{
    func animShow(){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseIn],
                       animations: {
                        self.center.y -= self.bounds.height
                        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
        self.isHidden = false
    }
    func animHide(){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: [.curveLinear],
                       animations: {
                        self.center.y += self.bounds.height
                        self.layoutIfNeeded()

        },  completion: {(_ completed: Bool) -> Void in
            self.isHidden = true
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be better for us if you will give some code which you was tried!

Comment: I have given the code.By this ,the view is animating from centre.but I need that from  bottom to whatever the height given to view

Comment: Before animation, self.bounds.height = 0. In animation, change the height to a value.

Comment: What is the initial `frame` of the `view` that you want to animate?

Comment: @axel,view hight should be 300, it should come from bottom

Answer (score 0):

Your `extension` functions works fine. In `viewDidLoad` set the frame of the animated view like the following example frame:

```
viewToAnimate.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.bounds.height, width: 100, height: 300)
```

and in your `viewDidAppear` trigger the animation:

```
viewTotAnimate.animShow()
```

This should give you the desirable animation from bottom to top.